# AnyLogic PICKUP – Agents become invisible after Pickup and during transport until Dropoff

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm encountering a problem in my AnyLogic simulation where agents (specifically materialTEST and materialBatchTEST) picked up from a queue by a pickup block become invisible during transportation and only reappear after the dropoff block. I've verified using the traceln() function that these agents are indeed being picked up and transported along with the container agent (workOrder).

In my model, a workflow is initiated by generating and sending a new workOrder agent into the enter block via a button (startTask). Following this, a worker is seized assigned to proceed to the first queue. Here, the worker uses a pickup block to retrieve two parts. The worker then moves to the second queue, where a batch block combines these two parts into a "permanent batch." Subsequently, the worker goes to the third queue to deposit this part. Finally, the worker returns to their home location. The logic of this process works fine, except for the issue of the agents (materialTEST and materialBatchTEST) becoming invisible after pickup and during the transportation until dropoff.

[My Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYVaf.png)

[Seize Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tebuz.png)

[Pickup Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaPf1.png)

[MoveTo Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpGcF.png)

Note: In another model, I create a custom agent block designed to represent multiple work processes, where various parts are picked up from the queue and transported. Thus, the solution needs to be applicable to all (different) agents that can be taken from the queue.

I've tried many solutions to resolve this issue without success and am looking for guidance or suggestions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the pickup block is for containers, so in your case your worker is swallowing the agents and then on the dropoff it pukes them back. You can only change the animation shape of the worker to represent the carrying of the agents

Comment: as Felipe says: this is by design. Either change the logic or the presentation of the worker